# How to set browser full width navigation?

Tags: html, css

I've to put a navigation along to the full width of the browser.
[image]

The problem is when click on the first item, along to the full browser width of that item shoild be effected.
[image]

This is also for last item
[image]

To do that, I've just worked with nav first-child and nav last child. You can see my work at [here](http://abidhasan.zxq.net/malden_molenhok/).

This works well at firefox. But, at chrome, if I zoom in/out the brwoser, the nav items will break.

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="header" class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-1.png" width="314" height="158" alt="logo" /></a></h1>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nieuws</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Praktijk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Behandelingen</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">ouderen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Algemeen</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Lorem...</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd55Roman';
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.outer {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;    
}
.inner {
    width: 941px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 22px 0 5px 0;
    background: url(../images/header-bg.png) repeat-x;  
}
h1.logo a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.nav { 
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
}
.nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;   
}

.nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.nav ul li a {
    min-width: 155px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 8px -21px;
    padding: 0 22px 0 32px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #cc3840;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd75Bold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 14px;
    background: #fff;
}
.nav ul li.active a, .nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #cf383c;
    background: none;
}
.nav ul li:first-child a {
    margin-left: -900%;
    padding-left: 900%; 
}
.nav ul li:last-child a {
    margin-right: -900%;
    padding-right: 900%;    
}
.nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #cf383c;
    background: none;   
}
    .nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        right: 0;
        display: none;
        z-index: 5; 
    }
    .nav ul ul li {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
    }
    .nav ul ul li a, .nav ul li:hover ul li a {
        width: 140px;
        display: block;
        background: #d0353e;
        color: #ffe597;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 6px 0 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 26px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 12px;
    }

    .nav ul ul li a:hover, .nav ul li:hover li a:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

#content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-top: 3px solid #fce696;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0; 
}
#content p {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 0;    
}
```

Can you please tell me how can I fix that for chrome and safari.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve from the description but try changing your pixels to percentages. If you want elements to stay positioned relative to each other, you need to use a relative unit of measurement or the layout will break when you resize.

Comment: The li a seems to conflict in Chrome. I suggest testing in www.jsfiddle.net and see if it also works that way in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set width to .nav > ul > li to fix this issue

```
.nav ul li:first-child, .nav ul li:last-child {
    width: 165px;
}
```

its working fine
    http://demo.sumedhasoftech.com/manoj/test/test.html

Comment: I think, this is not the solusion. I've set width at nav ul li. This showed different result at firefox and chrome

Comment: I set width at nav ul li. That's why, it's not worked. You set width at 
nav ul li:first-child and nav ul li:last-child. It works fine. Thanks a lot